# how to remove Dynamic report logo from Dynamic Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

the generated reports look like - http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/examples-overview#miscellaneous

The reports are good but it generates a logo of dynamicreports which i dont want, i searched on google but couldn't find any thing.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Look in your code and see if you can find "images/dynamicreports.png".

It should be in a piece of code that looks like..

```
  cmp.image(TestReport.class.getResourceAsStream("images/dynamicreports.png"))
     .setFixedDimension(80,80)
```

Basically you can change the image Url from there. Be sure to check out the getting started guide as well. You should see something related to this in the 'step 9: title' section.

http://www.dynamicreports.org/getting-started

Comment: Hi @SAZ thanks for the answer, I was using the sample code as it is and it had a Template once I removed it the logo went off. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * DynamicReports - Free Java reporting library for creating reports dynamically
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2010 - 2013 Ricardo Mariaca
 * http://www.dynamicreports.org
 *
 * This file is part of DynamicReports.
 *
 * DynamicReports is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * DynamicReports is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with DynamicReports. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

package net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.chart;

import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.cht;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.col;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.stl;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.type;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.TextColumnBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.FontBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.TimePeriod;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;

/**
 * @author Ricardo Mariaca (r.mariaca@dynamicreports.org)
 */
public class TimeSeriesChartReport {

    public TimeSeriesChartReport() {
        build();
    }




private void build() {
        FontBuilder boldFont = stl.fontArialBold().setFontSize(12);

        TextColumnBuilder<Date> orderDateColumn = col.column("Order date", "orderdate", type.dateYearToMonthType());
        TextColumnBuilder<Integer> quantityColumn = col.column("Quantity", "quantity", type.integerType());
        TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> priceColumn = col.column("Price", "price", type.bigDecimalType());

        try {
    report()
                .columns(orderDateColumn, quantityColumn, priceColumn)
                .summary(
                    cht.timeSeriesChart()
                        .setTitle("Time series chart")
                        .setTitleFont(boldFont)
                        .setTimePeriod(orderDateColumn)
                        .setTimePeriodType(TimePeriod.MONTH)
                        .series(
                            cht.serie(quantityColumn), cht.serie(priceColumn))
                        .setTimeAxisFormat(
                            cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Date")))
                .setDataSource(createDataSource())
                .show();
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("orderdate", "quantity", "price");
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 1), 50, new BigDecimal(200));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 2), 110, new BigDecimal(450));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 3), 70, new BigDecimal(280));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 4), 250, new BigDecimal(620));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 5), 100, new BigDecimal(400));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 6), 80, new BigDecimal(320));
        dataSource.add(toDate(2010, 7), 180, new BigDecimal(490));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Date toDate(int year, int month) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        return c.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimeSeriesChartReport();
    }
}
I am running this code still i am unable to  remove the image logo
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the package net.sf.dynamicreports.examples visit Templates.java file. In that you will find these lines of code:-

```
dynamicReportsComponent =
      cmp.horizontalList(
        cmp.image(Templates.class.getResource("images/dynamicreports.png")).setFixedDimension(60, 60),
        cmp.verticalList(
            cmp.text("DynamicReports").setStyle(bold22CenteredStyle).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT),
            cmp.text("http://www.dynamicreports.org").setStyle(italicStyle).setHyperLink(link))).setFixedWidth(300);
```

Remove the cmp.image() & cmp.text() element. It will stop displaying the images and the title of dynamic generator.